# Sorting Numbers and Text in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a jquery drop down table filter plug in for table filters:

https://github.com/rbayliss/Dropdown-Table-Filter

When I have a column in my table that is numerical however, the numbers are sorted as text, e.g. 1, 10, 100, 2, 20, 200 ...

in the code the sorter looks like:

```
  if(options.sortOpt) {
    opts.sort(options.sortOptCallback);
  }
```

I think this is a recursive call to:

```
sortOptCallback: function(a, b) {
 return a.text.toLowerCase() > b.text.toLowerCase(); 
},
```

how should I amend this so that it will sort numerical fields correctly? I have tried the following:

```
sortOptCallback: function (a, b) {
  if (isNaN(parseInt(a)) || isNaN(parseInt(b))) {
      return a.text.toLowerCase() > b.text.toLowerCase();
  } else {
      return a > b;
  }
},
```

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [sort not working with integers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/sort-not-working-with-integers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt is almost correct. The only problem is that you are still comparing the elements as strings after having determined that they are numeric. Furthermore, `sort` callbacks expect:

- A positive number if `a > b`
- A negative number if `a < b`
- Zero if they are equal.

With this in mind, try this callback:

```
if( a == b) return 0;
var anum = parseInt(a,10);
var bnum = parseInt(b,10);
if( isNaN(anum) || isNaN(bnum)) {
    return a.toLowerCase() > b.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;
}
return anum > bnum ? 1 : -1;
```

EDIT: @PaoloMoretti brought my attention to the fact that all your items are numerical. In that case, you can just do this:

```
return a-b;
```

Comment: Yeah, but the OP said that his table is numerical

Comment: Oh. So he did. Oops!"

Comment: still doesn't seem to work. I have put the code into jsfiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/7Ea36/

Comment: You aren't sorting numbers, you're sorting objects by one of their properties. Use `anum = parseInt(a.val,10);` and similar for `b`.